# How can I give a color name against a hex color code?

Tags: android, image-processing, color-picker

I have a code that can only give hex code on touch pixel on image. 
Now I want to give the name of the color as well. 
How is this possible using Android?? Please suggest a way.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // get x coordinates
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                // get y coordinates
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                // get bitmap in touch listener
                final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                //xand y coordinates stored in to pixel
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                //RGB values
                redValue = Color.red(pixel);
                blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
                greenValue = Color.green(pixel); 

                selected_colour.setText(""+redValue+""+blueValue+""+greenValue);
                selected_colour.setText("touched color:" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(redValue) + Integer.toHexString(greenValue) + Integer.toHexString(blueValue));

                selected_colour.setTextColor(pixel);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: There are `16777215` different hex color codes. I doubt there are enough color names to name all of these.

Comment: yeah but i have to add as much as possible ..

Comment: is there any library in android which return color name of hex color code  ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917978/how-can-i-give-color-name-to-hex-color-code-in-android

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is a bit tricky, because although there are many colours whose names are widely agreed upon (for instance, FFFFFF is called "White" everywhere), most other colour names are not a global convention but rather developed by the specific people who are naming the colours.

That being said, there are several tools out there which can do this. Check out [this link](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#FFFFFF), it's a website which you can provide a colour in hex code, and it will name it according to the closest pre-defined list of colour names.

You can view the [javascript code](http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/ntc.js) and adapt it to Android. It's a pretty straight-forward algorithm which measures the distance of the colour you gave to the closest hit in a predefined colour list, by measuring the distance in RGB and HSL.